# Inserting/Updating XMP in a PDF?

Tags: java, pdf, metadata, xmp

How can I insert/update some [XMP](http://www.adobe.com/products/xmp/index.html) metadata into a PDF file preferably using java ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [pdfmark](http://labs.crossref.org/pdfmark/) from CrossRef.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) library can be used to insert or extract those data. See http://plindenbaum.blogspot.com/2010/07/pdfbox-insertextract-metadata-frominto.html